# PowerShell Excel Add-in Deployment Issue

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory, add-in, gpo

I have this script that I have gotten from http://poshcode.org/1811 and modified slightly for my own purposes. The problem I'm having is the user who requested for me to deploy the add-in has informed me that only the initial person that logs on to use the add-in can see it installed. This is an Active Directory environment and the script is set to run as the user logs on.

Here is the script, I will also get the code for the add-in itself later from the person in question.

```
$Addinfilepath = '\\network\path\to\Excel Add-ins\'
$Addinfilename = Get-ChildItem $Addinfilepath -Name

ForEach ($CustomAddin in $Addinfilename) {
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $ExcelWorkbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
        if (($ExcelWorkbook.Application.AddIns | Where-Object {$_.name -eq  $CustomAddin}) -eq $null) {
            $ExcelAddin = $ExcelWorkbook.Application.AddIns.Add("$Addinfilepath$CustomAddin", $True)
            $ExcelAddin.Installed = "True"
            Write-Host "$CustomAddin added"}
#else{}
#{Write-Host "$Addinfilename already added"}
                                $Excel.Quit()
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong with the script, but I believe there's something going on where it's installing to the first person's profile on the PC, but then maybe the script is seeing it as installed period and then no longer installs to the next user that logs on.

Thanks for advice or help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you noticed it but you are missing $ sign in front of CustomAddin when you are trying to match the name.

```
Where-Object {$_.name -eq  CustomAddin})
```

should be

```
Where-Object {$_.name -eq  $CustomAddin})
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I believe that was actually as typo as I was formatting the post. I must've knocked it off there, as I just checked the copy of my script and the $ is present.